# Regular expression for spliting string to array

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I got a string like this:

```
== Paragraph == 
=== title 1 ===
content

=== Title 2 ===
other content 

== Paragraph 2 ==
=== asd1 ===
dfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfsdfdsf

=== asd2 ===
fgdfgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdg
```

I'm trying to parse it into array like this:

```
$arr = array( 
    array("title"=>"Paragraph", "content" => "=== title 1 ===
content

=== Title 2 ===
other content "),
array("title"=>"Paragraph 2", "content" => "=== asd1 ===
dfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfsdfdsf

=== asd2 ===
fgdfgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdg"));
```

I've tried this expession for getting paragraph names:

```
preg_match_all("@== (.*?) ==.*?@is", $data, $paragraphs);
```

but this expresion isn't working as I want, because it doesn't match the whole paragraph the output is like this and it doesn't get the contents:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Paragraph
        [1] => title 1
        [2] => Title 2
        [3] => Paragraph 2
        [4] => asd1
        [5] => asd2
    )
```

I have also tried ( nl2br cuz I don't know how to use new line in regex )

```
$data = nl2br($data);
preg_match_all("@== (.*?) ==<br />.*?@is", $data, $paragraphs);
```

but the result is something like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => == Paragraph == <br />
=== title 1 ===<br />
content<br />
<br />
 === Title 2 ===<br />
 other content <br />
 <br />
 == Paragraph 2 ==<br />
    )
```

I'm not understanding the regular expresions good and I can't figure out how to solve my problem.

Comment: This seems a lot like markdown, maybe have a look at a markdown parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe try this regex?

```
@(==[^=]+==)(.+?(?=[^=]==[^=]|$))@s
```

[Demo on regex101](http://www.regex101.com/r/uO9rT7).

Comment: Awesome then @Deepsy! ^^

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$str = '== Paragraph == 
=== title 1 ===
content

=== Title 2 ===
other content 

== Paragraph 2 ==
=== asd1 ===
dfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfsdfdsf

=== asd2 ===
fgdfgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdg';
$list = preg_split('/(?<!=)== (.+?) ==(?!=)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($list);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] =>
    [1] => Paragraph
    [2] =>
=== title 1 ===
content

=== Title 2 ===
other content


    [3] => Paragraph 2
    [4] =>
=== asd1 ===
dfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfsdfdsf

=== asd2 ===
fgdfgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdg
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we're breaking down each of the elements into its own piece of the array using `preg_match_all` and [look around assertions in RegEx](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php).

```
<?php

    $pattern = "~((?<!=)(?<=={2})\s*((?<=\s)[^=]+(?=\s))\s*(?=={2})(?!=)|(?<====)\s*((?<=\s)[^=]+(?=\s))\s*(?====)|(?<==\s)\s*((?<=\s)[^=]+)\s*(?!=))~";

    $string="== Paragraph == 
    === title 1 ===
    content

    === Title 2 ===
    other content 

    == Paragraph 2 ==
    === asd1 ===
    dfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfsdfdsf

    === asd2 ===
    fgdfgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdg";

    preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$matches);


    print_r($matches[0]);


?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Paragraph
    [1] =>  title 1 
    [2] => 
content


    [3] =>  Title 2 
    [4] => other content 

    [5] => Paragraph 2
    [6] =>  asd1 
    [7] => 
dfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfsdfdsf


    [8] =>  asd2 
    [9] => fgdfgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdg
)
```